# bibtex won't print

Tags: bibtex

Bibliography won't print, very minimal working example. I'm new to this stuff, and I can't find an answer in the LaTeX wikibook or by searching. No error messages, just nothing. I'm using Mac TeXShop latest version and the LaTeX compiler. Help!

Essay.tex:

```
\documentclass{article}

\begin{document}

kjghfhjjh \cite{Gib}\nocite{*}

%\bibliographystyle{alpha}
\bibliography{Essay.bib}

\end{document}
```

In Essay.bib:

```
@book{Shur,
    Author = {J. Shurman},
    Date-Added = {2018-05-02 10:28:52 +0000},
    Date-Modified = {2018-05-02 10:29:25 +0000},
    Publisher = {John Wiley and Sons},
    Title = {Geometry of the quintic},
    Year = {1997}}

@book{Lam,
    Author = {K. Lamotke},
    Date-Added = {2018-05-02 10:27:58 +0000},
    Date-Modified = {2018-05-02 10:28:45 +0000},
    Publisher = {Friedr. Vieweg und Sohn},
    Rating = {5},
    Series = {Advanced Lectures in Mathematics Series},
    Title = {Regular Solids and Isolated Singularities},
    Year = {1986}}

@mastersthesis{Hob,
    Author = {J. van Hoboken},
    Date-Added = {2018-05-02 10:26:50 +0000},
    Date-Modified = {2018-05-02 10:27:49 +0000},
    School = {University of Amsterdam},
    Title = {Platonic solids, binary polyhedral groups, Kleinian singularities and Lie algebras of type A, D, E},
    Year = {2009}}

@book{Gib,
    Author = {C.G. Gibson},
    Date-Added = {2018-05-02 10:25:36 +0000},
    Date-Modified = {2018-05-02 10:26:27 +0000},
    Publisher = {Pitman},
    Title = {Singular Points of Smooth Mappings},
    Year = {1979}}

@book{AGV,
    Address = {Boston},
    Author = {V.I. Arnold and S.M. Gusein-Zade and A. Varchenko},
    Date-Added = {2018-05-02 10:23:24 +0000},
    Date-Modified = {2018-05-02 10:24:57 +0000},
    Publisher = {Birkh\"auser},
    Rating = {5},
    Title = {Singularities of Differentiable Maps},
    Volume = {I},
    Year = {1985}}
```

Comment: Do you want to use `bibtex` or `biblatex`? Do you know that you have to run a separate program for both? I added a possible duplicate (Important bit: `(pdf)latex > bibtex or biber > (pdt)latex (twice).`).

Comment: Remove the  `%` before the `\bibliographystyle{alpha}`, the document needs a `\bibliographystyle` command. Remove the `.bib` from the `\bibliography` command: `\bibliography{Essay.bib}`, the file name of the `.bib` file must be given without the file extension. You also need to run BibTeX (see https://tex.stackexchange.com/q/63852/35864)

Comment: bibtex.
What separate program?
I have tried without .bib and with the style. I'm reading that article. I'm confused why this has to be so complicated though.

Comment: Have a look at the tutorial: https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=ZYvS52511oQ&list=PL-Wl6F3zpJVwcDHK2rg9bDEEMjo70zp87 (Disclaimer: it's my video)

Answer (score -1):

So apparently one has to type e.g.

```
bibtex Essay
```

into Terminal. Why in 2018 am I having to use command line when we have these flashy apps I don't know. Anyway, that's the solution. Someone should make this more clear on wiki.

Edit: The internet told me how to in the app. However I had tried this 10 times before, so I don't know what to say.

Comment: Any decent latex editor has a menu entry and sometimes a button to call bibtex -- and texshop is a decent latex editor.

Comment: No one forces you to type into Terminal. You are perfectly allowed to use a "flashy app", i.e. [some editor set up to work with LaTeX](https://tex.stackexchange.com/q/339/82917).

Comment: Complaining will not help. Maybe change to another software like MS Word or Open Office. You ask for help here: https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/129110

Comment: Side joke: *Compiling* will help though :)

Comment: Please note that you type in the name of your `.tex` file (without the `.tex`) and not the name of your `.bib` file here. I'm only saying this because your question shows that your `.bib` file is called `Essay.bib` to avoid confusion later on. Compiling in an app may not work if you have the `.bib` file open, often it is necessary to focus on the main `.tex` file when calling on the bibliography program.

Comment: Little bit mean guys if this was honestly a random error. I've been open, honest, grateful and courteous.

Comment: You shouldn’t be so against command line. Many bibliography related questions on this site would be avoided if new users started with learning how to use LaTeX on command line instead of using a front end. It helps you learn what is happening in the background.

Comment: Place the line `% !TEX program = pdflatexmk` at the top of your file and typeset using Typeset->Typeset (Cmd-T). The file will be fully processed.